# WordPress sub-menu items not displaying properly on hover on hover

Tags: wordpress, submenu, navigationbar

I'm creating a wordpress website and everything is nice and wonderful but I've run into a problem it seems... My sub-menu is not properly showing up. It doesn't work on mobile either. I'm quite lost. It was working and then just stopped.

http://vps17582.inmotionhosting.com/~eterna39/wp/

Thank you in advance. I hope I get this solved fast so I can launch my site sooner than later.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to remember what you have donne between the time its was working and now. What have you change? Have you make updates? Have you tried to disable plugins? … Have you check if there is not an update of your theme? Have you tried to search in support threads of your theme and ask there too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You submenu is there but the overflow hidden is blocking it.
remove overflow hidden from the class navbar

```
.navbar {
    /* overflow: hidden; */ 
}
```

Comment: responsiveimage slider (plugin?) is responsible for this issue. adding `.navbar { overflow: visible!important; }` at the bottom of your style.css will override this problem. you can edit it from **appearance>editor**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Adding the overflow: visible!important } was the way to go. I can't believe I didn't think of that. I thought it was possibly a z-index issue.

Thanks guys!